# Why LWC component is reloading due to the recordtypeId is changed in Record Edit Form

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, lwc-dom, lightning-record-form, refresh-view-api

My LWC component has lightning-record-edit-form, and it is working fine in normal scenario. But whenever there is an update in recordtypeId field, it reloads the whole page.

things I already checked:

1. no navigation mixin
2. only on-submit and on-success is getting called
3. record page assignment is same for all recordtypes and profile
4. Object: LiveChatTranscript
5. console tab is reloading evne if the recordtype id is updated in trigger(tried it as a work around)

This is only happening only when **RecordTypeId** changes, on any other fields update, LWC **works fine**

I am using wire methods to get object info and retrieving the recordtypeinfo from schema and then passing this recordtypeid to other wires to retrieve/update record (a simple operation) using record edit form, showing record id in the form.

I have never see wire reloading the console tab.

Below is the pseudo code:

```
<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name={objectName} class="full-width" record-id={recordId}
    onsubmit={handleSubmit} onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
```

HandleSubmit

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.toastMsg) return;
    this.showSpinner = true;
    const fields = event.detail.fields;
    if (this.wrapperData != null && this.wrapperData.field4.length > 0 && this.objRecord.Field1 != null && this.objRecord.field2 != null) {
        let flagToStopRecurssion = true;
        if (this.showSpinner && (this.fieldsChanged.has('Field1')
            || this.fieldsChanged.has('field2')
            || this.fieldsChanged.add('RecordTypeId'))) {
            try {
                //populate fields on submit
                fields.RecordTypeId = this.rtIdFromLogic;
                fields.field2 = this.objRecord.field2;
                fields.Field1 = this.objRecord.Field1;
                this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);
            }
            catch (err) {
                this.showSpinner = false;
                this.dispatchEvent(new ShowToastEvent({ title: 'Error', message: err.message, variant: 'error', }),);
            }
        }
        if (this.fieldsChanged.has('field3') && this.fieldsChanged.has('field5') && this.fieldsChanged.has('field6')) {
            saveValuesInOtherRelatedObject({ deleteList: JSON.stringify(this.deleteListRecords), insertList: JSON.stringify(this.insertListRecords) })
                .then(result => {
                    if (result != '') {
                        //Showing error if any from apex
                        this.dispatchEvent(new ShowToastEvent({ title: 'Error', message: result, variant: 'error', }),);
                        this.showSpinner = false;
                    } else {
                        this.insertListRecords = [];
                        this.deleteListRecords = [];
                        if (flagToStopRecurssion) {
                            this.handleSuccess(event);
                            flagToStopRecurssion = false;
                        }
                    }
                }).catch(error => {
                    
                    this.dispatchEvent(new ShowToastEvent({ title: 'Error', message: error.body.message, variant: 'error', }),);
                    this.error = error;
                    this.showSpinner = false;
                });
        }
        
        if (flagToStopRecurssion) {
            this.handleSuccess(event);
        }
    } else {
       
        this.showSpinner = false;
        this.dispatchEvent(new ShowToastEvent({ title: 'Error', message: 'errormessage', variant: 'error', }),);
    }
}
```

Handlesuccessmethod:

```
handleSuccess(event) {
//event.preventDefault();
this.toastMsg = "";
this.dispatchEvent(
    new ShowToastEvent({
        title: 'Success',
        message: 'success message',
        variant: 'success',
    }),
);
this.showSpinner = false;
this.fieldsChanged = new Set();
```

}

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Is there a question here? I can only assume you are asking why this is happening and how to avoid it? Are you editing the contextual record? If so, I suspect this relates to the lightning data service and the fact that record type can have a major impact on presentation of the record.

Comment: Its on the record page so yes I am editing contextual record. After update i want to show the values or refresh values, so using wire methods.  
Livechattranscript is a standard object But the same things i am doing on a custom object record as well in exact same manner and same logic, in that on recordtype update page is not refreshing.

Comment: **To solve this we had to remove the record type field update and store it in some other custom field.**

Comment: You should provide a self-answer so you can mark your response as answering the question.